# PHP Form Creating XML

Tags: php, html, xml

I've been trying to create a form to create known issues for our tech support group for RSS feed however it does not seem to be creating the XML.

I've tried to keep it as simple as possible but I may have kept it too simple and overlooked something.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" action="generate.php" method="post">

Name of Issue: <input name="name" type="text" /><br/><br/>
Core Service(s): <input name="service" type="text" /><br/><br/>
Severity:<br>
<form>
<input type="radio" name="severity" value="Sev1">Sev1<br>
<input type="radio" name="severity" value="Sev2">Sev2<br>
<input type="radio" name="severity" value="Sev3">Sev3<br>
</form> <BR/> <br/>
Team Looking into Issue: <input name="Team" type="text" /> <BR/> <br/>
ETA (if known): <input name="ETA" type="text" /> <BR/> <br/>
Comments: <textarea name="comments" cols="50" rows="5">

</textarea><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Backend generate.php

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['create_issue'])){

        echo "Issue Posted";

        $xmlfileName = "issues.xml"

        $name = $_POST['name'];

        $service = $_POST['service'];

        $severity = $_POST['severity'];

        $Team = $_POST['service'];

        $ETA = $_POST['ETA'];

        $comments = $_POST['comments'];

        $xml_dec = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>";

/* After Receiving data for issue created generate XML*/

        $rootELementStart = "<knownissue>";

        $rootElementEnd = "</knownissue>";

        $xml_doc=  $xml_dec;

        $xml_doc .=  $rootELementStart;

        $xml_doc .=  "<name>";

        $xml_doc .=  $name;

        $xml_doc .=  "</name>";

        $xml_doc .=  "<service>";

        $xml_doc .=  $service;

        $xml_doc .=  "</service>";

        $xml_doc .=  "<severity>";

        $xml_doc .=  $severity;

        $xml_doc .=  "</severity>";

        $xml_doc .=  "<team>";

        $xml_doc .=  $team;

        $xml_doc .=  "</team>";

        $xml_doc .=  "<eta>";

        $xml_doc .=  $ETA;

        $xml_doc .=  "</eta>";

        $xml_doc .=  "<comments>";

        $xml_doc .=  $comments;

        $xml_doc .=  "</comments>";

        $xml_doc .=  $rootElementEnd;

        $default_dir = "";

        $default_dir .=   $xmlfileName .".xml";

/* Write XML */

$fp = fopen($default_dir,'w');

            $write = fwrite($fp,$xml_doc);
            }
?>
```

Comment: is anything at all created?  or nothing?  Are you sure your script has write permissions there?

Comment: Script has full permissions and nothing is created at all. Also the Echo is not appearing as I added that to help me know that it was working or not.

Answer (score 1):

This line is missing a semicolon:

```
$xmlfileName = "issues.xml"
```

Dont forget to [fclose](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php) your file too! You can get some useful error information that way.

Comment: Aw man I can't believe I didn't see that... and yes I will add fclose. It is still not appearing to work however. It maybe something with the frontend backend that isn't working is my worry now.

Comment: @Ericrs - this looks to answer the question...if it doesn't you should elaborate, if it does, you should check it as correct.